# Product tab not coming in admin in Magento2.2

Tags: magento2.2

My code was working fine for Magento 2.1 but in 2.2 suddendly product tab is not coming in magento admin on product edit page. below is my layout file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_form">
            <block class="W3solver\Qrcode\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Qrcode" name="qrcode.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qrcode</item>
                        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">191</item>
                        <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                        <item name="group_code" xsi:type="string">advanced</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string"></item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> In W3solver\Qrcode\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Qrcode
>   file

When I tried to debug then it works till constructor but later its not working. Is there any change with Magento 2 which can result in such issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use below code in your module then **view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_form.xml**

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <htmlContent name="qrcode" sortOrder="22">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wrapper" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qrcode</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <wrapper>
                <canShow>true</canShow>
                <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
            </wrapper>
        </settings>
        <block class="W3solver\Qrcode\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Qrcode" name="qrcode">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qrcode</item>
                    <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">191</item>
                    <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                    <item name="group_code" xsi:type="string">advanced</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string"></item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </htmlContent>
</form>
```